# grails multi-level has-one domain reletionship

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am new to stackoverflow.And I have to create domain mapping such that

`class User {
    transient springSecurityService
    transient String confirmPassword
    String username
    String passwor
    static hasOne = [profile:Profile]
    boolean enabled = false
    boolean accountExpired = false
    boolean accountLocked = false
    boolean passwordExpired = false
    static transients = ['springSecurityService','confirmPassword']
    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true, validator:{ value,obj ->
            if(value==obj.password)
            {
                return "com.cyberespion.beans.User.username.validator"
            }
        }
        password blank: false, length: 8

        username blank: false, unique: true, validator:{ value,obj ->
            if(value==obj.password)
            {
                return "com.cyberespion.beans.User.username.validator"
            }
        }
        profile nullable: true,unique:true
    }
    static mapping = {
        password column: 'password'
        version false
    }
    User()
    {
        profile=new Profile()
    }
}`

`package com.cyberespion.beans

class Profile

{

    String firstname
    String lastname
    String email
    String website
    String phone
    String company
    TimeZone zone
    static hasOne = [address:Address]
    UserProfileRoleEnum role
    EmailPackage requirement
    EmailPackage emailPackage
    static belongsTo =[user:User]
    static constraints = {
        firstname blank:false
        lastname blank:false
        email blank:false, unique: true, email: true
        website blank:false, unique: true, url: true
        phone unique:true, blank:false
        company unique:true,blank:false
        zone blank: false
        address unique:true, nullable:true
    }
    static mapping = { 
        version false
    }
    public Profile()
    {
        this.emailPackage=EmailPackage.getEmailPackage("Lite 0 to 200")
        address=new Address()
    }
}`

`package com.cyberespion.beans
class Address {
    String country
    String state
    String city
    String address1
    String address2
    int pin
    static belongsTo =[profile:Profile]
    static constraints = {
        pin size: 6, blank:false
        country length: 25, blank:false
        state length: 30, black:false
        city length: 30, blank: false
        address1 length: 120, blank:false
        address2 length: 120, blank:true
    }
    static mapping={
        version false
    }

}`

When I save User a profile and Address should be saved. But I am getting null pointer exception.

What I should do.

Comment: Is that the code that you have so far?

Comment: Without seeing how you are creating the instance(s) it's going to be impossible to give you any help. I would recommend including that in your post.